# Reattach and lazy load exception

Tags: java, hibernate

I am facing a lazy load exception which I cannot figure out.
First I fetch with a usual find method from the entity manager an entity. After that I run method which part of it is :

```
object = getUnproxiedValue(object);
if (object == null) {
    ... // this part is not run
    return;
}
if (object instanceof Collection ) {
    ... // and I fall here with lazy load exception
    return;
}
```

The getUnproxiedValue suppose to give object when the argument object is a proxy, the proxy is initialized (loaded) and the un-wrapped object is returned. Something goes wrong beacuse when there is a collection sometimes it dies with an lazy load exception, beacuse object is null so why the first condition did not work ?

For any clues and hints thank you in advance, and I really greatly appreciate any support in this.

Regards,
P.

Comment: Could you please add the code of getUnproxiedValue?

Comment: instanceof also checks for nulls, so it always returns false if object being checked is null

Answer (score 0):

`LazyLoadingException` identifes that you're trying to get data from db without a transaction. Try use `@TransactionAttribute` annotation to ensure you run your `if (object instanceof Collection ) {` block in transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using EJB Beans? Your entity Object is detached, when you leave the transaction. So you cannot load any dependent Entities (lazy Loading). You could use an extended persistence context entity manager together with a stateful session bean. Then you can use lazy loading outside a transaction. And your Entity is keep in sync with the database.